# How many isolated points can a degree $d$ planar curve have?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $p(x,y)\in\mathbb R[x,y]$ be a bivariate polynomial of degree $d$. What is the maximum possible number of its acnodes (i.e. isolated roots in $\mathbb R^2$ not counting multiplicities)?

A pretty decent construction is $\prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor d/2\rfloor} (x-a_i)^2+\prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor d/2\rfloor} (y-b_i)^2$, giving ${\lfloor d/2\rfloor}^2$ isolated points.

As mentioned in [Roots of bivariate polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77334/roots-of-bivariate-polynomials), an upper bound is ${d-1\choose2}+1$ given by Harnack's curve theorem.

Those two bounds agree when $d=2$ or $4$. When $d=3$, the lower bound is correct.

By Bezout's theorem, one can show that if the, say, irreducible polynomial is a sum of squares, then ${\lfloor d/2\rfloor}^2$ is the best we can do.